# Problema al rellenar JTABLE con ArrayList

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipse, arraylist, jtable

Buenas noches stack**overflow**... Les escribo porque tengo un problema, que, hasta los momentos no he podido resolver, ya tengo 2 dias escribiendo y borrando codigo... El problema consta de:

Yo cree una pequena interfaz grafica, para ser mas exacto, un formulario en swing, entonces, el formulario consta de: **Nombre, ID, Direccion, gener y hobbies.** Entonces, estos datos los recojo con un ACTIONLISTENER en un JBUTTON, y ok, me recoje los datos y me los guarda en el respectivo ARRAYLIST. Cabe destacar que, me crea un objeto cada vez que lleno el formulario, por ende, puedo agregar N cantidad de personas... Bueno el problema radica en que, cree una clase en donde cree mi JTABLE, y quiero pasarle los datos del arraylist a la tabla. El codigo que tengo es:

```
    public class TablaPanel extends JPanel{

DefaultTableModel modelotabla;
JTable tabla1;
JScrollPane scroll1;
Object columnas[] = {"NOMBRES","CEDULA","DIRECCION","SEXO (M/F)","HOBBIES"};
Object[] fila = new Object[contador.contadorfilas];

 Persona pnew = new Persona(); //esta es la clase que tiene las variables de persona
 FormularioCapa contador = new FormularioCapa(); //para poder obtener contador de cada vez que se presiona 
                                                                                    //el jbutton

public TablaPanel(){

    modelotabla = new DefaultTableModel(columnas,0); //0 son las filas

    tabla1=new JTable(modelotabla);
    add(tabla1);

    ArrayList<Persona> list = lista.getListaDePersonas();


    for(int i=0;i<contador.contadorlista;i++){
    fila[i]=pnew.getName1();
    fila[i]=pnew.getCedula();
    fila[i]=pnew.getAddress();
    fila[i]=pnew.getGender();
        modelotabla.addRow(fila);
    }
    //CONTADORLISTA es para agregar n Filas, y esa n lo define un contador que va sumando 1, cada vez que 
    //se agrega una nueva persona (o sea, cada vez que se presiona el jbutton)

    scroll1 = new JScrollPane(tabla1);
          add(scroll1);

}
```

EL problema es que, NO me muestra el texto en las celdas del JTABLE. Pero si toma en cuenta lo de contador. Es decir, si agrego 5 personas, me toma en cuenta las 5 filas y las agregas, pero NO la data de las filas, solo agrega las filas vacias sin ningun tipo de informacion...

Cabe destacar que tengo un System.out.println, que me muestra el arraylist completo una vez agregadas las n personas, y si las guarda (n cantidad de personas con sus datos que sean agregadas mediante la interfaz grafica). La cosa radica en que, no me las muestra (las personas agregadas y su informacion) en las celdas del JTable...

Es mi primera vez trabajando con JTABLE, espero entiendan. Saludos y feliz noche

Comment: A las variables de la clase `Persona` le tienes declarados valores por defecto. Puedes agregar el codigo donde le asignas valores a los objetos Personas.

Answer (score 2):

Tu tabla parece estar bien definida. El problema que veo es que a la hora de insertar las filas, estás insertando el número de filas correcto pero estas insertando siempre los datos de un objeto `Persona` vacío. No estás utilizando los objetos `Persona` de tu `ArrayList`. Por esta razón, ves las filas pero el contenido de las mismas está vacío.

Prueba a borrar ese objeto persona vacío que tienes y cambia tu bucle `for` de la siguiente manera:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    modelotabla.addRow(new Object[] {list.get(i).getName1(), list.get(i).getCedula(), list.get(i).getAddress(), list.get(i).getGender(), list.get(i).getHobbies()});
}
```

> NOTA: No necesitas en ningún momento decirle al modelo cuántas filas
>   tiene que añadir de manera implícita (en tu caso, con el contador  que
>   le estás pasando al `for`), ya que ya se lo has dicho antes
>   al darle nombre a las columnas.

Comment: Buenas noches, excelente respuesta amigo. Me sirvio mucho. Pero una vez que lo hice asi como me explico, igual no me agregaba nada. Entonces, en la clase donde tengo el arraylist declarado con sus getters y setters, coloque [code] private static ArrayList<Persona> listaDePersonas = new ArrayList<Persona> [/code], es decir, la declare como static y fue cuando me pudo y logro agregar a la tabla. De resto, no me lo permitia.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido :)